# Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$. Then prove that $H$ is normal in $G$. (Serge Lang.)

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$. Then prove that $H$ is normal in $G$.

The following proof for the above statement was given in Serge Lang's book on Algebra.

> Note that $H$ is contained in it's normalizer, so the index of the normalizer in $G$ is either $1$ or $2$. If it's $1$ then we are done. Suppose it is $2$. Let $G$ operate by conjugation on the set of subgroups. The orbit of $H$ has two elements, and $G$ operates on this orbit. In this way we get a homomorphism of $G$ into the group of permutations of two elements. **Since there is one conjugate of $H$ unequal to $H$, then the kernel of our homomorphism is normal, of index $2$, hence equal to $H$, which is normal, a contradiction which concludes the proof.**

Now I understand most of the proof besides the part marks in bold. Like what does it contradict? The fact that the normalizer has an index $2$? Why? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think that in your title you want *index* instead of *order*.

Comment: Please fix the question. Not only is the title wrong, but the body of the post does not contain the statement you are trying to prove (making reference to the **false** statement in the subject line). Posts should be *self-contained*, and not rely on the subject line for key information (especially when you  mess up the latter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We’re assuming at that point that the normalizer of $H$ has index $2$ in $G$. If $H$ is normal, however, then its normalizer is $G$, which has index $1$, not $2$; this is the contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that makes sense, I'm sorry if the question was too straightforward.

Comment: @AbhijithRao: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another proof if you are interested:

If the index of H in G is 2, it has only two cosets in G---the subgroup H itself, and some other coset. This second coset must be a left coset as well as a right coset, thereby forcing H to be normal.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, this is easier than the proof in Lang.